# jquery function $(document).ready and $(document).on('mouseover mouseout', ...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my symfony application i have a jquery $(document).ready function that looks like that:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var button = $(".addFieldButton");

    $(button).click(function (e){
        //... click function
    }
}
```

The thing is i can also add lines which contain a new `.addFieldButton`-Button which doesn't work because the function is only instanciated once when the document is loaded so i also want to reinstanciate this function when the user clicks the `.addLineButton`-Button like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout','.addLineButton',function (){
    var button = $(".addFieldButton");

    $(button).click(function (e){
        //... click function
    }
}
```

But when i only use this function the `.addFieldButton`-Button that exists from the start on, only works when i hovered over the `.addLineButton`-Button. Is there a way to combine these to functions?

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Thank you all, i will have a look at this